# Bower install does nothing

Tags: javascript, bower

I am using bower with my rails4 project.

Here is my bower.json

```
{
  "name": "sinestro",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ind9/sinestro",


"authors": [
    "Bharath ツ <bharathraja@live.com>"
  ],
  "description": "Product Catalog",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "app/assets/javascripts/lib/bower",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.10.4",
    "backbone": "~1.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.0",
    "underscore": "~1.7.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.14",
    "requirejs-text": "~2.0.12",
    "image-center": "git://github.com/boxlight/bl-jquery-image-center",
    "spin.js": "~2.0.1",
    "numeral": "~1.5.3",
    "ix" : "git@github.com:ind9/magneto.git"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery-ui": "~1.11.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0"
  }
}
```

and here is my .bowerrc

```
{
  "directory": "bower_lib"
}
```

The bower version is 1.3.12. When I say bower install - it prints the log that it resolving dependencies and fetching it - but it doesn't install it anywhere. There is no directory named bower_lib is getting created. Can someone help me? And there are no errors in the output as well.

Comment: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/414